# Glade file opens but no details

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

Glade 3.14.2 seems to open my .glade file, but displays nothing.  I can see all xml details in text editor.  Headers in my .glade file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<glade-interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 2.16 -->
  <!-- interface-naming-policy toplevel-contextual -->
  <widget class="GtkWindow" id="mainwindow">
```

... ending with ...

```
</glade-interface>
```

Am I missing something or have the wrong version?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your ui xml is stored in old *libglade* format.

Since *libglade* is deprecated, you can try to convert this xml to *GtkBuilder* format:

```
gtk-builder-convert foo.glade foo.ui
```

Note, that *gtk-builder-convert* is in *libgtk2.0-dev* package on Debian.

Also note, that you will have to update ui creation code to *GtkBuilder* too, here goes the skeleton:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk

class Skeleton(object):       
    def __init__(self):
        builder = gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("foo.ui")
        builder.connect_signals({ "on_window_destroy" : gtk.main_quit })
        self.window = builder.get_object("mainwindow")
        self.window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Skeleton()
    gtk.main()
```

You may also try to change root xml element from `glade-interface` to `interface` before opening it in recent glade designer, however, I can't recommend that.

Comment: Tried this, but had some errors.  Ended up just installing Glade 3.8.